# Django remove Timezone

Tags: python, django

I'm doing a query on a table in postgres with a datetime field with timezone support. I'm doing a distinct select to group all the results by hours in the day.

```
footage = IpCameraFootage.objects.filter(ipCamera=c, start__gte=start, end__lte=end).extra(select={'hours': "to_char(start,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24')"}).values_list('hours', flat=True).distinct().order_by('hours')
```

This is all working great however when I iterate over the results. It's applying a timezone conversion. I'm trying to get the direct value from the database without the timezone. For example, if it's returning a value of:

```
05/03/2013 07
```

When I access the hours variable in a django view using the following:

```
for f in footage:
   print f
```

the value is:

```
04/03/2013 21
```

Any ideas how to get the result that's it's supposed to be?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Can the formatting function you are doing in the extra statement being replaced by a pure python command on the returned queryset?

something like

```
from django.utils.timezone import utc

for f in footage:
    print('{0:%d/%m/%Y %H}':format(f.start.replace(tzinfo=utc)))
```

otherwise, in templates, according to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#template-tags), you may use

```
{% load tz %}

{% localtime off %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocaltime %}
```